# How will you identify if this is web server / code / vm shortage

Tags: perl, virtual-machine, virtualbox

given a whole picture first.

In a Oracle VM box, I've installed a WinXP pro(x32) and a Web server. The web server's web root, CGI scripts, and interpreter are mounted from share folders from my host computer(my real C drive), which the folders are read-only.

My problem is, when I create any (CGI) web pages with frames (or iframe), it happens to throw Error 500 in random frame (even I run the page from localhost), but if I reload the frame, or reloads the whole page, it can go normal again (this also happen a first ok frame go error after reload the whole page). And I've checked very carefully, there's no problem for my script. btw, I use Perl for my CGI scripts.

So I suspect there might be some problem along the "traffic" though in the same machine, but I don't know if this can happen if I call the same module among those different frames. Anyone experience similar situation or relative information? or if any test plan you would suggest me to do? I am recently using Abyss x1 as my web server, but I tried Apache also, and same thing happens

Thanks in advance

Comment: A 500 error should have an explanation in the error logs. Look there for hints (E.g. premature end of script headers tells you that you haven't considered all execution paths in your CGI script. Or maybe you threw a fatal error).

Comment: @amon Ah ha! That's good one! I never considered to check the log while I am not dealing with real errors! And now I really got something, which I couldn't figure why this happen... First, it comes with <code>attempt to reload POSIX.pm aborted.</code> and blah blah blah chain effect errors and end up by <code>"broken pipe" </code>. Any idea that's my Perl's error? or the network's broken? ( as said, when I reload the frame, it always goes no problem )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows XP [does not allow more than 10 incoming connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882) and is therefore not a good operating system on which to install a web server.

> Note For Windows XP Professional, the maximum number of other computers that are permitted to simultaneously connect over the network is ten. This limit includes all transports and resource sharing protocols combined. For Windows XP Home Edition, the maximum number of other computers that are permitted to simultaneously connect over the network is five. This limit is the number of simultaneous sessions from other computers the system is permitted to host. This limit does not apply to the use of administrative tools that attach from a remote computer.

Comment: Um.. is that anyway I can check if I've crashed on such bottle neck? For my development, I only run on 4 frames at max (but I am not sure if there's any underlying threads filled up this limit), or is that any setting I can put it on some "waiting" status rather than "drop"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do a `netstat -an`, look at the inbound connections. If you have a page, 2-3 images on the page, a few clients connecting, you going to hit the limit very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amon and Sinan, that gave the clues. These 2 are reasons why this happen ( only don't sure if they are all the reasons). Since the interpreter and underlying modules also calling from host machine, which is quite expensive. After I installed a Perl(and modules) inside my VM. This problem won't happen again!